# php ADODB call mysql_options() before connection to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

My application is using ADODB to connect simultaneously to 2 MySQL DB. Application is downloading large files; it takes a lot of time so "mysql has gone away" error takes place.

I know that MySQL allows to use automatic reconnection which could be enabled using mysql_options(), but I have no clue how to apply this function to ADODB adapter.

```
    $DB = NewADOConnection('mysql');
    $DB->Connect(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DBNAME);
```

Thank you for you time!

PS: Probably I should ask how to get DB handler variable from $DB? If I could get DB connection handler from ADODO as $handler I could use mysql_options($handler, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, 1); But how could I get $handler if I should call mysql_options() before connection (according to MySQL reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html )

Comment: mysql_options() function seems to be unavailabe at PHP MySQL API :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set mysql options, you can use dsn. This is my connection template that I always use:

```
$options = '';
if ($driver == 'mysql' OR $driver == 'mysqli')
{
  if ($params['pconnect'] === TRUE)
  {
    $options .= '?persist';
  }
  $flags = MYSQL_CLIENT_COMPRESS;
  $options .= (empty($options)?'?':'&')."clientflags=$flags";
}

$dsn = "{$driver}://{$username}:{$password}@{$hostname}/{$database}{$options}";

if ($driver == 'sqlite')
{
  if ($params['pconnect'] === TRUE)
  {
    $options = '?persist';
  }
  $database = urlencode($database);
  $dsn = "{$driver}://{$database}{$options}";
}

$adodb =& ADONewConnection($dsn);

if ($adodb)
{
  //set fetch mode
  $adodb->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_BOTH);

  //character set
  if ($driver == 'mysql' OR $driver == 'mysqli')
  {
    if (isset($params['char_set']) AND $params['char_set']
        AND isset($params['dbcollat']) AND $params['dbcollat'])
    {
      $charset    = $adodb->qstr($params['char_set']);
      $collation  = $adodb->qstr($params['dbcollat']);
      $adodb->Execute("SET NAMES $charset COLLATE $collation");
    }
  }
  if ($debug)
  {
    @ob_start();
    $adodb->debug = TRUE;
  }
}
```

You can omit the `sqlite` driver conditional block if you will only use this for MySQL.
Apparentlt, PHP MySQL client only support limited option, [here is the list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.constants.php). You can try MySQLi, it [have more options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php).

Have you try the persistent connection istead?

Comment: MySQLi lib is exactly what I was looking for. Don't you know is ADODB supports MySQLi?

Comment: Thank you. I've found MySQLi driver in ADODB drivers. Will try right now.

Comment: To know what drivers in ADODb, just take a look inside `drivers` folder. The driver file name follow this format: `adodb-[DRIVER_NAME].inc.php`